# limit the number of threads for part of a spark rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a spark job that does a ton of mapping from different system, as part of this it fetches some data from a remote api (with caching). If it hits the cache, all is well, if it doesn't it bombards the api (which has a rate limit).

One attempt I've made is to filter out the pieces of it that requires download, and run the downloads seperately. However, I can't find out how I can make sure a forEach runs on for example one thread (or preferably, has some shared counter that allows me to see how many requests I've made within the last minute to see whether or not I've hit the api limit).

I can do it by setting up a custom spark config, but then I'll have to do a ton of filtering/mapping twice. Once to make sure all the downloads are done, and then again to load them from cache and keep parsing.

Answer (score -1):

> has some shared counter that allows me to see how many requests I've made within the last minute to see whether or not I've hit the api limit

The answer is yes, Please refer to the shared-variables in pyspark document.
[Spark Programming Guide - Shared Variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables)

Comment: broadcast is read only, and accumulators cant be read from within the worker, so neither of those will help me very much